# ¿Por qué no carga phpmyadmin en wampserver o lo hace una sola vez y a su vez ocasiona que no pueda entrar a localhost?

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wampserver

escribo porque desde ayer que empecé a utilizar phpmyadmin en wampserver estoy presentando problemas. Antes de usar phpmyadmin todo iba a bien con el servidor, pero cuando empecé  a usarlo sucedieron estas cosas: A veces nunca entra a la página de phpmyadmin y se queda siempre cargando, otras veces si entra pero luego si doy click a algo o quiero actualizar la página, entonces no carga, y a veces el nada más intentar entrar a phpmyadmin ocasiona que ni siquiera pueda entrar a localhost. Cuál podría ser la razón? Intenté estas soluciones y no funcionaron:

1. Borrar las cookies de google chrome que es el navegador que estoy usando con wampserver
2. Desactivar las extensiones de google chrome
3. Usarlo en una ventana incógnita de google chrome
4. Cambiar al puerto 8080 a pesar de que aunque estaba usando el 80 y creo que todo iba bien con el 80, igual lo cambié al 8080 y aún así no funcionó. Cuando cambié al 8080 lo hice dando click a la opción "Use a port other than 80" en el menú de wampserver.

De todas formas esta es la captura de pantalla del testeo del puerto 80:
[image: 80]

La versión de wampserver que estoy usando es la 3.3.2 de 64 bits, la versión de phpymyadmin es la 5.2.1 y la de php es la 8.3.0

Comment: Estimado, esta respuesta te puede ayudar <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows> Para ver si hay un proceso que esta ocupando el puerto 80, en tu caso se ven que el PID es 7076, en el CMD ejecutado como administrado puedes insertar este comando para dar de baja ese proceso.
```
taskkill /PID 7076 /F
```

Comment: Ah ok ok, pero si le doy de baja no afectaría al servidor? Porque como dice que es un proceso del servidor